# What does the <?= tag mean?

Tags: php, tags, php-shorttags

I'm using CakePHP.

Today I tried to link a page of the Page Controller to another page from the Page controller, and I couldn't get to see the link until I wrote

```
<?= $this->Html->link('myPage', array('controller' => 'pages', 'action' =>
    'myPage')); ?>
```

Why did I have to write `<?=` and not `<?php` ?

Generally speaking, when do I have to use `<?=` and when `<?php` ?

Comment: Doing some proper researches now that I know the answer, I found out that this is just a duplicate of a lot of other similar questions. Should I delete this question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`<?=` is short for `<?php echo`

Add `echo` to your code and it will work.

This is not unique to CakePHP, it's just part of PHP.

Comment: I guess it's me being really noob then! I'll edit post title and remove CakePHP tag. Thank you!